# What is the mercurial equivalent of 'svn cat'?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I want to print the contents of a single file from a remote repository, at a specified revision. How can I do that? In svn, it'd be:

```
svn cat <path to remote file>
```

#### update

The main thing I want to avoid is cloning the entire repository; some of the ones I'm working with are quite large, and I just need project metadata from a single file within.

Comment: You can use the mercurial web interface (built in via `hg serve`) to download particular revisions of particular files...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two ways to do what you want:

1. Clone the repository locally, and execute the appropriate `hg cat -r REV FILE` against it
2. Use a web interface that gives access to the remote repository

If you don't have the web interface, then you need to clone.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to download the file content with `wget` or your favorite browser. For example, for bitbucket repositories the URL looks like this:

```
http://bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>/raw/<revision>/<filename>
```

For the `hg serve` web interface, the URL looks like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/raw-file/<revision>/<filename>
```